# Symfony 2 - Create Form with child entities & upload file

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'm having a problem when trying to create a Form that handles an Entity that is related to 2 more Entities.

I have a "Template" entity:

```
class Template
{
  /** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="template_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
  private $templateId;
  private $name;
}
```

An entity "TemplateMessage", which has a "OneToOne" uni directional relationship with "Template", this is, one Template can have only one Message, but the TemplateMessage only know to which Template it belongs:

```
class TemplateMessage
{
  /** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(name="template_message_id", type="integer")
 */
  private $templateMessageId;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="text")
   */
  private $html;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="text")
   */
   private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Template", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="template_id", referencedColumnName="template_id")
 */
private $template;
}
```

And finally, an entity for attachments for that Template:

```
class TemplateAttachment
{
/** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(name="template_attachment_id", type="integer")
 */    
private $templateAttachmentId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $size;

private $file;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\TemplateMessage", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="templateMessageId", referencedColumnName="templateMessageId")
 */
private $templateMessage;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
```

}

After this, I have an HTML form created, that handles the creation of the Template, with its messages and should allow to upload files, all in a single form, I need to do it that way (That is, can't break the form)

Well, my problem is:

How do I create a Form that handles all this? I read the chapter about Forms in the Symfony Book, and the form render OK, but when try to add a new Template, as I need a Template ID for the TemplateMessage to be created, an Exception obviously is raised. 
My solution was to create a Form based NOT in the Template but in the Template Message like this:

```
class TemplateMessageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('subject', 'text')
            ->add('html', 'textarea')
            ->add('text', 'textarea')
            ->add('template', new TemplateType())
            ->add('file', new TemplateAttachmentType())
       ;
    }
}
```

Being the TemplateAttachmentType:

```
class TemplateAttachmentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'E5P\CoreBundle\Entity\TemplateAttachment'
        ));
    }
}
```

My problem is that an error is thrown:

Neither the property "file" nor one of the methods "getFile()", "file()", "isFile()", "hasFile()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "CoreBundle\Entity\TemplateMessage"

I don't want to start the creation of the Form from the last child entity, but in a "natural" way of creating a Template and add the Types for all the child entities (Those would be TemplateMessage & Template Attachments")

I'm new to Symfony, and maybe I'm doing the things in a wrong way, any ideas?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you entities' properties are `private`, but you don't have getters and setters. I'd add getters and setters to the entity classes and go from there.

Comment: All the entities has the setter & getters, and, despite that, the $file attribute is raising the error and the set & get are there.